# getting dataframe from scraped data with scrapy

Tags: python, dataframe, scrapy

I want to create a data frame with scraped data using scrapy that contains three columns;title,link and date.
This is my code:

```py
class LaquotidienneSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'laquotidienne'
    
    start_urls = ['http://laquotidienne.ma/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for articles in response.css('div.list_article_detail'):
            items=[]
            item={
                "title":articles.css('a::text').get().replace('\n',' ').strip(),
                "link":"https://laquotidienne.ma/articles/economie",
                "date":articles.css('span::text').get()
            }
            

        for i in range(2,501):
            next_page="https://laquotidienne.ma/articles/economie/"+str(i)
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

            items.append(item)
        
        df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['title', 'link', 'date'])
```

But unfortunately it's not working, i get :

```
name 'df' is not defined
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In general, you want to explain what "not working means". Is there an error ? If so, what is it ? Is the result not what you expected ? If so, what did you expect and what did you get ? Why do you think the result could cause the unexpected result ? Have you tried using assertions to confirm the state of variables and/or the result of calculations is what you expected it to be ? How did you use the above code ?  ....

Comment: the problem is that error is name 'df' is not defined even though i defined it.

Comment: you have to create global `df` and global `items = []` outside function `parse`. But scrapy can automatically write all results in file `csv` and you could later run other script to read `csv` to `DataFrame` and process it.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is that with *every page* you scrap you repeat the following**

- create a new list called items - actually you do this with every item you scrap-
- extract the item
- do the requests from page 2 - to the end, NOTE: every time you parse a new page you do this, though scrapy only visits the page 1 but still you shouldn't do that
- define a new dataframe

**what my code does**

- start the requests only one time from the top of the code
- parse each page separately
- extract the elements and append it to the global list `items`
- and after the spider finishes and closes `closed` comes into play
- read the global list into a dataframe
- do whatever operations you want, in my case i saved the output in csv

**how to run the code**

- `$ scrapy startproject stack_code`
- `$ cd ./stack_code`
- `$ scrapy genspider laquotidienne "http://laquotidienne.ma/"`
- write the following code in `stack_code/stack_code/spiders/laquotidienne.py`
- `$ scrapy crawl laquotidienne`

**the code**

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd

# the global list
items = []

class LaquotidienneSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'laquotidienne'

    def start_requests(self):
        '''The right Method to start the requests'''
        
        for i in range(1, 10):
            next_page="https://laquotidienne.ma/articles/economie/"+str(i)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
    
    def parse(self, response):
        '''Method to parse each page'''
        
        for articles in response.css('div.list_article_detail'):
            # extract the item
            item = {
                "title":articles.css('a::text').get().replace('\n',' ').strip(),
                "link":"https://laquotidienne.ma/articles/economie",
                "date":articles.css('span::text').get(),
            }
            
            # add the item to the global list
            items.append(item)
    
    def closed(self, reason):
        '''Method to be called after the spider finishes'''

        # create datafrane from the global list 'items'
        df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['title', 'link', 'date'])
        
        # do whatefer operations you want
        df.to_csv('Test.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: same error appears: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: @Sebastian please follow the steps in the new edit and update the question with the error if any.